# How to set only two numbers that appear after the comma when exporting reports to excel from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Currently I'm using this code to export my PHP to excel. Everything's is fine and code is work. But I curiously want to know how to set only 2 numbers after the comma? For example for "percent", the result is like "63.3333" or "72.3456". How to make it just 2 number after the comma when the report opened by excel?

```
$queabsdetail = "SELECT archieve AS archieve, SUM(barang_in) AS income, SUM(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out) AS outcome, SUM((bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out)-barang_in) AS efficiency, SUM(barang_in/(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out))*100 AS percent FROM items GROUP BY archieve";
$exequeabsdetail = mysql_query($queabsdetail);
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($exequeabsdetail)){

    $data['id_transaction'][] = $res['id_transaction'];
    $data['archieve'][] = $res['archieve'];
    $data['income'][] = $res['income'];
    $data['outcome'][] = $res['outcome'];
    $data['efficiency'][] = $res['efficiency'];
    $data['percent'][] = $res['percent'];



} 

$jm = sizeof($data['id_transaction']);
header("Pragma: public" );
header("Expires: 0" );
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header("Content-Type: application/force-download" );
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" );
header("Content-Type: application/download" );;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=archieve_report.xls " );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary " );
xlsBOF();
xlsWriteLabel(0,3,"Archive Report" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,0,"Number" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,1,"Archieve" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,2,"Income Items" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,3,"Outcome Items" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,4,"Efficiency" );
xlsWriteLabel(2,5,"Percent" );
$xlsRow = 3;

for ($y=0; $y<$jm; $y++) {
    ++$i;
    xlsWriteNumber($xlsRow,0,"$i" );
    xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,1,$data['archieve'][$y]);
    xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,2,$data['income'][$y]);
    xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,3,$data['outcome'][$y]);
    xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,4,$data['eficciency'][$y]);
    xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,5,$data['percent'][$y]);
    $xlsRow++;
}
```

I've tried with :

```
number_format($data['percent'],2);
```

but it seems doesn't work for exporting data. But it works when I use it in PHP. So how the tricks?

Comment: I take if your comma is what most everyone else in the world would use a `.` for? 63.3333 with .3333 being the fractional part? I don't know what excel library you're using, but any decent one should be able to define number formats as you would in the real Excel program, and let you set how many decimal places you want displayed.

Comment: @MarcB hehe sorry, in my country most of people using "," for comma. But I just edited it, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a nicer way to do it, but quick and dirty this should work:

```
xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,5,round($data['percent'][$y]));
```

Comment: but I already multiplying that by 100 in my query.

`SUM(barang_in/(bijih_out+htm_out+pth_out))*100 AS percent`

If i do that again, there's no comma. hmm

Comment: hey I do change some parts of your code, and it works when I apply that in my code. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: In that case just take out the multiplier. edit: I've done that to the example above.

Comment: ya I just tried with `xlsWriteLabel($xlsRow,5,number_format($data['persen'][$y],2));`

and it works, thank you ;)